# Need to run cron as authenticated user

Tags: cron

Hi on my server I need to be running cron as an authenticated user in order for the directories that I need to access during a specific function to be writable.  How can I make cron or at least part of this cron run be run as an authenticated user for drupal 8.  I found some documentation but only for drupal 7 .
thanks

Comment: Aren't the server directories writeable regardless of what user is logged in?

Comment: not in this specific environment, because of security concerns

Comment: So cron needs to run a specific server user, or Drupal user? What is controlling the logic to what uploaded file folders are writeable by role?

Comment: I am not sure what permissions I need, I get this error : : failed to open stream:                                             [warning]
"Drupal\Core\StreamWrapper\TemporaryStream::stream_open" call failed file.inc:956

Comment: I am closing this question since it is about code the OP wrote, but the code isn't shown. It doesn't even seem a Drupal question, since using a Drupal account instead of another one doesn't change the file system permissions for a directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can run your custom cron methods as an authenticated user as follows:

```
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

/**
 * Implements hook_cron().
 */
function my_module_cron() {
  // Login as user 1
  $user = User::load(1);
  user_login_finalize($user);

  // Your custom cron functions

  // Login as user 0 (anonymous)
  $user = User::load(0);
  user_login_finalize($user);
}
```

Comment: What does this mean? Doesn't this only work for cron implemented in one module and not others?

Comment: You should include this code in your custom cron method so it only works for your custom cron functionality. I will update my answer to clarify.

Comment: I still get this error scandir(private://default/): failed to open dir: "Drupal\Core\StreamWrapper\PrivateStream::dir_opendir

Comment: Do you see the following message in your dblog: 'Session opened for <user>' on cron run? If so you implemented my code above correctly and I guess that your problem is not related to Drupal permissions.

Comment: Hi I do not see that message "Session opened " etc.

Comment: Hi I get a message "Class 'user' not found"

Comment: \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1)   I had to do it like this but then I still get the errors.

Comment: I think that you should create a new question since your problem isn't solved by running the cron as an authenticated user. Post back the link to your new question and I will have a look at it.

Comment: In Drupal 8, there is a class method to safely impersonate a user. From the question it's not even clear that is really necessary, as the question is about a file system permissions for a directory, which aren't changed because of the Drupal account used. Maybe the OP is confusing Drupal accounts with OS accounts.